# What does "pad your wallet" mean in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The headline from the NY Times is:

> Follow the experts for sidewalk finds that enliven your home or pad your wallet.

I can only imagine that means to save money but I also imagine that "pad your wallet" is a reference to something else; is it so?

Comment: Nope, it's just a playful way of saying "save money." Even if people keep most of their money in a bank account, "your wallet" can be used here to refer to all your money. "Pad" as in "make thicker."

Comment: [Definition of "pad"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pad) as a verb: *to expand or increase especially with needless, misleading, or fraudulent matter*

Answer (score 3):

Not so much 'save money' as 'get money': the verb *to pad* can mean *to stuff*, that is *to add additional material* (see the definition on [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pad), for example).
The article's title implies you can find valuable items on the sidewalk, either in the form of home decoration or in the form of good old-fashioned coins or bills.

Comment: Agree "pad your wallet" means to make money, but in this particular case it would come from selling found items rather than finding cash itself.